# calling C from epicenter

Tags: forio-contour

My world is computational statistics and I thought I would try out forio-epicenter for creating applications.  Clearly I am able to call Python functions from forio-epicenter.  However, am I able to call a Python function that calls a C function?

Comment: yes you can call C functions in Python, you have the code the bridge to fill the gap tho, https://docs.python.org/2/extending/extending.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is possible, though it may be mildly tricky. You'll have to compile the C code to a shared library, and it'll have to be compiled for 64-bit Linux (Ubuntu, though that shouldn't really matter too much). That shared library will have to be uploaded to your model directory in Forio Epicenter.

For wrapping the C library, there are three possibilities, more or less. SWIG doesn't require any support from Forio to be usable, you'll build the Python wrapper off-line and upload it to your model directory. Cython or CFFI can both be supported, though as of this writing they aren't. If you're interested, let us know, and support can quickly be added for either of those solutions (and it is planned to do both eventually anyway).

- [Swig](http://www.swig.org/)
- [Cython](http://cython.org/)

*Disclaimer: I currently work at Forio*

Comment: I plan to rewrite my existing Python/Cython/C code in Juila anyway, but it is a bit long and involved.  It would be nice to try it out as-is in the epicenter system, but it is certainly not important.  Thank you.